# How to change color of the window

Tags: java, swing, colors

I am making a networking app in java, which is a server that connects several terminals together.  I wanted to give the server app a darker feel (grays and blacks), however I cannot seem to change the background color from its default light gray.

Here's a picture of my application so you can tell what I'm doing:

[image: picture of program]

I tried using

```
this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(50, 50, 50));
```

however that didn't change the background color.  I also tried changing the JScrollPane's background and foreground color, but that didn't do anything.

Changing the table's background only makes the background of the cells darker, not the rest of the window.  Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

EDIT:
Here is my code so far:

```
JTable serverList;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    Container container = this.getContentPane();

    public GuiMain()
    {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(50, 50, 50));
        serverList = new JTable(Variables.servers, Variables.serversHeader);
        serverList.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(serverList);
        serverList.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
```

Comment: If you don't show us some code, how could we know what you have in there (JFrame, JScrollPane, custom contentPane of what ever type...) ?

Comment: The JTable covers all the window, so the background color must be set on JTable not on its container

Comment: Thanks, however when I edit the background of the JTable, it only affects the cells, not the rest of the window.  

I added my code so far so you can see what I've done.

Comment: Actually, Aubin, that did work, but is there a way to get the table to not cover the entire window?

Answer (score 1):

The ScrollPane takes up the whole window, so the light-gray background you are trying to get rid of is from the ScrollPane's Viewport. Here is how to change it:

```
scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(new Color(50, 50, 50));
serverList.setFillsViewportHeight(false);
// ^-- so that the JTable does not fill the Viewport
```

Comment: Answer edited: Changed `setFillsViewportHeight(true)` to `...(false)`.

Comment: @Ryan Sparks: If this answer does indeed solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will know it is a working solution.